# Windows on Parallels 10 with 2 out of 3 monitors only

Tags: macbook-pro, display, parallels-desktop

I've MacBook Pro with 2 external monitors connected. Is there a way to configure Parallels so that it allows you to use 2 monitors for Windows and the main one for Mac? I only found option to make it all or just 1. Also I don't want to expand Windows across the 2 monitors (i guess there's an option to do that). I want them treated as separate spaces so i can easily move things around between 2 monitors (for example Outlook on one, chrome on the other).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) seems to work fine for me, I've found it in a post on the [Parallels Forum](http://forum.parallels.com/threads/full-screen-for-2-of-3-monitors.279937/#post-716602):

> I will start the VM with 3 screens, then I use a 3rd party software (UltraMon) and disable the one display so that my VM uses two screens running Windows 7 and my MacOS uses the one.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Comment: @patrix the solution is simple (Use Ultramon). He also gave a description. I believe it's legit answer. Short one but it has a point.

Comment: Haha, patrix was actually the one who edited my answer to provide the helpful blurb :) @MadBoy

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is referenced [here](https://forum.parallels.com/threads/full-screen-for-2-of-3-monitors.279937/#post-862715).

My setup is as follows:

1. Parallels Desktop v15.1.5
2. MacOS Catalina v10.15.7
3. Windows VM running in full screen mode
4. MacBookPro 15" 2018
5. 3 external monitors + the 1 MacBookPro laptop screen
6. One of my external monitors "owns" the menu bar within System Preferences > Displays (this seems to make the MBP screen always appear as monitor #2 in Windows).

Steps:

1. Download (and decompress) the MultiMonitorTool to a folder inside your Windows VM https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html. Note the full file path where you save the MultiMonitorTool.exe tool.
2. Open startup folder: Within Windows VM > do Windows Key+R [or Cmd+R] (alternately click start > type "run" > click the run search result)
3. type "shell:startup" in the run textbox > enter (this will open the startup folder)
4. Right click within your startup folder > new > Text Document > rename the document to "TurnOffMonitor.bat"
5. right click TurnOffMonitor.bat > Edit (this will open notepad)
6. paste the following using the path you saved to above (note this disables monitor 2 which is my MBP screen but you may need to adjust this number for your setup):

`<path>\MultiMonitorTool.exe /disable 2`

7. Save TurnOffMonitor.bat file
8. Start > Power > Reboot your Windows VM
9. upon startup, it should disable whichever monitor is marked as #2

If your unsure what number your monitor is, run the MultiMonitorTool.exe > top pane > look at the "Name" column which has the monitor #.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after thinking about it for a bit I decided to go with coherence mode which seems to do this in a bit different way then I wanted it (no desktops etc) but it may serve it's purpose of being able to mix MAC/Windows enough to move windows around easily.

Comment: Yes, it works, but feeling a bit weird. Maybe i'll work it out and just need to get used to it.